# Add item to a 2nd list by index of item in the 1st list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 lists.

I have an Angular service with a `splice`-based method that allows me to remove items from the first list (called "`items`") based on their index via a `ng-click` action.

```
  service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  };
```

What I would like to do is to add the removed item to the 2nd list (called "`bought`"), using the same index that is passed to `slice`.

I thought perhaps I could put this functionality into the same function ( `removeItem` ) like this:

```
  service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    bought.push(itemIndex);
    items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  };
```

However, that does not seem to work. I tried a few variations (like `bought.push(items.itemIndex)`) unsucessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `splice` to insert the element to be removed at the same index in the second array.

```
service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    var currItem = items[itemIndex];
    // Insert the element to be removed
    // at the same index in the other array
    bought.splice(itemIndex, 0, currItem);
    items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  };
```

or instead of accessing the element before hand, use the one returned when the element is removed.

```
service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    var currItem = items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    bought.splice(itemIndex, 0, currItem);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to splice removes the item from the array, which is good. It returns the element that it removed. See doco here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

So your removeItem function could look like this:

```
service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    var removedItem = items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    bought.push(removedItem);
};
```

Problem is, you are making the removeItem method do 2 things at once. It might be better to rename it to reflect what it is doing (eg "buyItem").

Or have a higher level function that does this

```
service.buyItem = function (itemIndex) {
    bought.push(removeItem(itemIndex);
}
service.removeItem = function (itemIndex) {
    return items.splice(itemIndex, 1);
};
```

That way your removeItem function is pure in what it does and can be used elsewhere

Comment: Thanks Mike. I think you're absolutely correct in the first part. I don't know if I could separate the adding and removing into 2 different functions though, because when the button gets clicked to remove the item from the first list it should appear in the 2nd list. I don't want to have to introduce another button. Or is it possible to give 2 different functions to `ng-click`? Sorry if that's obvious, I'm only a week into learning Angular.

Comment: It's not a big deal, usually someone writing a service suggests an advanced level, because services can be used from other places in the code quite easily - generally people put utility functions in services. If you just give it a more descriptive name then it will be fine. You can become fully pro next week :)